# How to dynamically change observable of a VM

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following viewmodel and what I try to achieve is that when a user click a button, this sub-viewmodel get changed and UI updated accordingly. Currently my btnClicked method is called but the UI is not updated. here is an example of my vm

```js
var model1 = {
  name : ko.observable('john')
};

var model2 = {
  name: ko.observable('jane')
};

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.model = model1;
  self.btnClicked = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    self.model = model2;
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span data-bind="text: model.name"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: btnClicked">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your bindings, your HTML. Presumably nothing is updated because `self.model` is not an observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VM self.model is not an observable variable.
Following is what you can do to get that work properly

```
<body data-bind="with:model">
  <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: btnClicked">Click me</button>
</body>

var model1 = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable('john');
};

var model2 = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable('jane');
};

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.model = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.model(new model1);

  self.btnClicked = function() {
     self.model(new model2);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

working example :http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5145/

Comment: thanks matt; you example does work around my issue here but can not take it as my model need to have either a model1 or model2 property without having to to change the root view model (in my real app i have many of these )

Comment: actually it does make it work . What i don t get is the usage of with . IF instead you put the full path (model.name) it then stops to work

Comment: @Dave `model` is a knockout object and it won't work like that , if you want to use full path you need to change it to `<span data-bind="text:model().name"></span>` and remove `with binding`

Answer (score 0):

The very first problem that I see, within your code/html:  Your text binding for **model.name** is bound to a non-observable.  While the **name** properties of **model1** and **model2** are observables, the objects themselves are not.  As such, it is not an object that Knockout would properly work with.
  Also, I would not say that the way that you are assigning values to the **self.model** property of the viewmodel is a standard practice.  I suggest checking out the KnockoutJS tutorial website; there are a lot of good examples to give you a better understanding of Knockout there.

Comment: I think that changing the my model to a regular observable will not fix the issue (actually i have tested it)

Comment: It will not fix all of the issues, no.  It fixes the initial problem, where your span is never even shown as a visible element because the text binding has no effect on the view the user is shown. I am looking at this right now in Plnkr and it does, indeed, change the behavior to actually show the span contents _initially_.  There are other issues, but I see another answer that addresses some of those as well, and would direct your attention to that one also.  There was also a need to change your binding to model().name.